# How to pass / use a variable from Servlet to included JSP within the Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a servlet that prints out the content to the screen.
I'd like to use JSP for the content and include it into servlet via

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/content.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Is there any way to Servlets variables in this included JSP without forwarding the request to it?

Comment: You would use the exact same way as if you forwarded the request: a request attribute.

Comment: Ok, so I did request.setAttribute("variable", "test"); before include. In the JSP I'm trying to String my_variable= request.getParameter("variable"); and print of my_variable is always = null

Comment: You're setting an attribute, and then you're getting a parameter. Those are very different things. Use getAttribute().

Comment: Hover the [jsp] and [servlets] tags you placed on the question until a black popbox shows up and then click therein the *info* link. This should get you started the right way as to learning JSP and Servlets.